# unable to copy a database inside the same server using the Copy Database wizard

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have sql server 2008 R2. and I want to take a copy of a database inside the same database server. so I will have exact copies of the database. now I  login to the sql server management studio>> right click on the database >> tasks>>copy database. where I was prompted with the copy database wizard. I select the database I want to copy, and I name the new copy as `Test_Copy`, and I select to run the operation immediate ... now I got this error:-

[image]

so can anyone advice what might be causing this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Is SQLServerAgent running?

Comment: @GaaraofDesert why do I need to run it ?

Comment: @GaaraofDesert and does the Copy Wizard support copying the database inside the same sql server ?

Comment: Because error says that agent is not running. Start agent and then try again.

Comment: If there is an option to create sql query in wizard, you can create it and then run it in Management studio. UPD: it seems that there is no such option. So you should start agent

Answer (score 1):

You need to open up the Server is SQL Server Management Studio and find the SQL Server Agent at the bottom under the server and right click then start.
[image]

If you would rather you can log onto the server and find services and then scroll down until you find SQL Server Agent Services and start those. Doing either rof these should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the copy database wizard, i get the following dialog when Agent is not running [image: Agent Warning]

It's my understanding that the wizard creates a package with a series of steps that is all managed by the agent. Because the agent is controlling and sequencing the process, it needs to be enabled.